# Vandermonde determinant of the elements of a finite field

Tags: prime-numbers, determinant, finite-fields

Let $p$ be a prime and let $V(p)$ denote the Vandermonde determinant
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
V(p)
& = &
\left|
\begin{matrix}
1&1&1&\cdots&1&1\\
0&1&2&\cdots&p-2&p-1\\
0&1&4&\cdots&(p-2)^2&(p-1)^2\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\\
0&1&2^{p-2}&\cdots&(p-2)^{p-2}&(p-1)^{p-2}\\
0&1&2^{p-1}&\cdots&(p-2)^{p-1}&(p-1)^{p-1}
\end{matrix}
\right|
\\
& = &
\left|
\begin{matrix}
1&1&1&\cdots&1&1\\
0&1&2&\cdots&-2&-1\\
0&1&4&\cdots&4&1\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\\
0&1&2^{p-2}&\cdots&(-2)^{p-2}&-1\\
0&1&2^{p-1}&\cdots&(-2)^{p-1}&1
\end{matrix}
\right|
\end{array}
$$
of the elments of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ ordered as $\{0,1,2,\dots,p-2,p-1\}$.

Computations suggest that

- when $p\equiv 1[4]$, then $V(p)$ is a root of $-1$,
- while if $p\equiv 3[4]$, $V(p)$ is most often $=1$, and sometimes $=-1$.

The first few values for which $V(p)=-1$ are:

`[3, 7, 47, 59, 79, 83, 103, 107, 127, 139, 191, 199, 211, 251, 263, 283, 307, 331, 367, 379, 383, 431, 467, 479, 499, 503, 547, 587, 599, 607, 631, 643, 659, 727, 743, 811, 823, 827, 839, 859, 863, 883, 887, 907, 971, 991, 1087, 1151, 1163, 1171, 1259, 1283, 1307, 1319, 1367, 1423, 1427, 1459, 1483, 1487, 1511, 1523, 1531, 1583, 1619, 1627, 1663, 1699, 1783, 1787, 1811, 1823, 1871, 1951, 1979, 1987, 2011, 2027, 2039, 2063, 2083, 2099, 2111, 2143, 2179, 2243, 2251, 2267, 2287, 2311, 2339, 2383, 2411, 2423, 2447, 2459, 2467, 2503, 2539, 2551, 2591, 2699, 2707, 2711, 2719, 2731, 2767, 2843, 2851, 2879, 2887, 2971, 2999, 3019, 3067, 3079, 3119, 3167, 3187, 3191, 3203, 3251, 3299, 3319, 3331, 3347, 3359, 3391, 3407, 3467, 3491, 3499, 3511, 3527, 3539, 3559, 3571, 3583, 3623, 3671, 3739, 3779, 3803, 3823, 3863, 3907, 3923, 3931, 3967, 4007, 4019, 4051, 4079, 4099, 4127, 4139, 4211, 4219, 4259, 4271, 4423, 4447, 4519, 4567, 4583, 4591, 4603, 4663, 4831, 4931, 4999, 5003, 5023, 5059, 5087, 5099, 5107, 5147, 5167, 5171, 5179, 5227, 5323, 5351, 5387, 5431, 5503, 5507, 5519, 5531, 5563, 5623, 5647, 5651, 5659, 5683, 5711, 5743, 5783, 5791, 5807, 5827, 5839, 5879, 5903, 5923, 5939, 5987, 6011, 6067, 6079, 6091, 6131, 6143, 6163, 6211, 6263, 6299, 6311, 6343, 6359, 6367, 6491, 6547, 6551, 6563, 6571, 6599, 6607, 6659, 6719, 6779, 6791, 6803, 6823, 6863, 6871, 6899, 6967, 6983, 7019, 7027, 7043, 7079, 7103, 7151, 7159, 7207, 7211, 7219, 7351, 7451, 7459, 7487, 7507, 7523, 7547, 7591, 7603, 7607, 7687, 7691, 7699, 7703, 7727, 7759, 7867, 7879, 7919, 8039, 8087, 8111, 8167, 8219, 8287, 8291, 8311, 8363, 8419, 8443, 8467, 8543, 8699, 8707, 8719, 8779, 8783, 8807, 8831, 8839, 8863, 8867, 8923, 8971, 9043, 9059, 9103, 9127, 9203, 9283, 9311, 9319, 9403, 9419, 9463, 9479, 9511, 9539, 9551, 9587, 9619, 9631, 9643, 9719, 9743, 9767, 9787, 9871, 9907, 9931, 10007, 10039, 10091, 10139, 10151, 10159, 10163, 10211, 10243, 10247, 10259, 10267, 10271, 10331, 10391, 10427, 10459, 10463, 10487, 10531, 10559, 10651, 10663, 10667, 10711, 10723, 10799, 10867, 10883, 10891, 10903, 10939, 10979, 10987, 11003, 11027, 11047, 11071, 11083, 11087, 11279, 11287, 11299, 11311, 11351, 11399, 11411, 11491, 11519, 11527, 11551, 11579, 11719, 11779, 11807, 11839, 11903, 11939, 11971, 12071, 12143, 12163, 12203, 12239, 12251, 12263, 12343, 12347, 12491, 12503, 12539, 12583, 12647, 12739, 12743, 12763, 12799, 12911, 12923, 12967, 12983, 13003, 13043, 13099, 13127, 13147, 13151, 13163, 13183, 13187, 13219, 13259, 13267, 13327, 13399, 13411, 13487, 13523, 13567, 13591, 13691, 13711, 13759, 13807, 13831, 13859, 13879, 13903, 13963, 14107, 14159, 14207, 14243, 14303, 14323, 14423, 14431, 14447, 14503, 14627, 14683, 14699, 14723, 14731, 14747, 14759, 14767, 14771, 14783, 14827, 14831, 14843, 14851, 14867, 14879, 14887, 14891, 14939, 14951, 14983, 15083, 15091, 15107, 15131, 15187, 15199, 15287, 15307, 15331, 15383, 15391, 15451, 15511, 15551, 15559, 15643, 15667, 15727, 15739, 15767, 15803, 15823, 15887, 15907, 15923, 15971, 15991, 16007, 16063, 16103, 16139, 16267, 16319, 16363, 16411, 16447, 16451, 16487, 16547, 16567, 16603, 16651, 16703, 16747, 16759, 16763, 16787, 16811, 16831, 16843, 16927, 16979, 17011, 17123, 17167, 17183, 17203, 17207, 17239, 17299, 17359, 17387]`

This sequence of numbers is known to the OEIS as [A129518](https://oeis.org/A129518) and [A260298](https://oeis.org/A260298) (but for the $2$)

---

I can prove the assertion relative to $V(p)$ being a root of $-1$ when $p\equiv 1[4]$ and $V(p)=\pm1$ otherwise: if $p\equiv 1[4]$, then on account of $\binom{p}2$ being even, we get that
$$V(p)^2=\prod_{i\neq j}(j-i)=(-1)^p=-1$$
so that $V(p)$ is a root of $-1$,
while if $p\equiv3[4]$, $\binom{p}2$ is odd and we get
$$V(p)^2=-\prod_{i\neq j}(j-i)=-(-1)^p=1$$
so that $V(p)=\pm1$.

---

> For $p\equiv 3[4]$, is it known when $V(p)=1$ and when $V(p)=-1$?

I can try to generalize the question to finite fields, and this requires us to order the elements of a finite field $\mathbb{F}$. We can forget about $0$ and use a generator of $\mathbb{F}^\times$ as a yard stick:

> More generally, if $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field of size $q$ and $\xi$ is a primitive element (i.e. generator of $\mathbb{F}^\times$), is the value of the determinant $|\xi^{ij}|_{0\leq i,j<q-1}$ known?

Comment: There should be a closed formula. Your determinant, in the general case, is a discriminant of a polynomial $x^{p^{n}} - x$, since this has roots equal precisely to elements of the field $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$.

Comment: @RybinDmitry The discriminant of you talk about ought to be the square of $V(p^n)$.

Comment: you are right, via discriminant we can only obtain $V^{2}(p) = (-1)^{\frac{p^{n}\cdot (p^{n} + 1)}{2}}$.

Comment: I'm running the computation to get more primes satisfying $V(p)=-1$. I'm looking in the first 2000 primes.

Comment: @RybinDmitry I added more primes that work. I'd love if there were a closed form, but I'm skeptical there is one. There is no obvious pattern in the residues, say.

Comment: Among the first 2000 primes, 522 satisfy $V(p)=-1$, and 491 satisfy $V(p)=1$.

Comment: I have a vague recollection of somebody posting here (a link to) a formula for the determinant of the DFT-matrix $|\xi^{ij}|$ but couldn't find it. May be it was in a comment? The closest match I found were related to determinants of character tables. But there the sign is obviously left ambiguous, so the results didn't contain anything you wouldn't know already :-(

Comment: [Wikipedia on the eigenvalues of the DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors). That is for complex roots of unity, but should generalize to other fields. Of course, to solve your main question we also need the sign of the permutation converting the linear order of residue classes into the sequence of powers of a primitive element.

Comment: Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen The sign of that permutation is indeed the crucial point, as the two matrices are the same up to permutation of the columns according to that permutation. On that note, when $q$ is an odd prime power, and when $\xi$ and $\zeta$ are two generators of $\mathbb{F}^\times$, the signature of the permutation of $\mathbb{F}^\times$ sending $\xi^i$ to $\zeta^i$ is $1$.

Comment: Indeed, $\zeta=\xi^a$ for some $a$ coprime to $\varphi(q-1)$, and if $\omega$ is its order in $(\mathbb{Z}/(q-1)\mathbb{Z})^\times$, then the sign is $(-1)^{r(\omega-1)}$ where $r$ is the number of orbits besides $\{1\}$. But $1+r\omega=q-1$ so $r\omega$ is odd, and so $r(\omega-1)$ is even and the signature is one.

Comment: Then I guess the natural thing to try to prove is that there is a simple expression for the DFT determinant when $q\equiv 3[4]$, and to reduce everything to the sign of the permutation of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ sending $\zeta^i$ to $i+1$ or so.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen the comments are mainly for me ^^, as this is exactly what you propose.

Comment: Understood. Sorry I cannot say anything really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reference discussing this determinant: [Wilson Theorems for Double-, Hyper-, Sub- and Super-Factorials](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.3676.pdf) establishes that $V(p)\equiv(p-1)!!\mod p$, where $n!!$ is the double factorial, the product of the positive integers $\leq n$ with the same parity as $n$. Their **Theorem 3** describes the sign $V(p) = (-1)^\nu$ for $p\equiv 3[4]$ in terms of $\nu$, the number of quadratic nonresidues $2< qnr < \frac{p-1}2$. And **Theorem 4** gives yet another description of $V(p)$ in full generality.